# Why does % give different answers when an arithmetic expression has floating points?

Tags: java, operators, modular-arithmetic

I recently started learning java and this question keeps on bugging me..

```
    class Example{
        public static void main(String args[]){
        double d;
        d=4.1 % 1.1;
        System.out.println("4.1%1.1 : "+d);

        d=5.5 % 1.1;
        System.out.println("5.5%1.1 : "+d);
        }
    }
```

the output for the above program is 
4.1%1.1 : 0.7999999999999994 and 
5.5%1.1 : 1.0999999999999996

but when we do these calculations by hand, we get 0.8 for the first one and 0 for the second one... why does this happen??

% gives the correct answer when integers are used in the expression..

```
    class Example{
        public static void main(String args[]){
        int x;
        x=10%17;
        System.out.println("10%17 : "+x); **//prints 10**
        }
    }
```

can anyone pl explain what exactly happens here?

Comment: Have you read [the definition of `%` in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)?

Comment: `.1 ` is an endless fraction in binary. But computers do calculate with *fix width numbers*, so any calculation with `.1` *must* be wrong.

Comment: Modulo tells you the remainder of that division. The remainder of `4.1 / 1.1` is `0.8`: `1.1 * 3 = 3.3; 4.1 - 3.3 = 0.8`.

Comment: @BackSlash thanks for showing it to me.. i mistyped

Comment: @TimothyTruckle hmm.. is that so.. ill refer the web page u gave.. thanks

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947044/how-do-i-use-modulus-for-float-double

Comment: @DiliniPeiris These are precision issues. You get `0.7999999999999994` because `double` can't handle `0.8` without precision loss. same for the other number. If you use `BigDecimal`, this issue disappears. [Demo](http://ideone.com/TrMvNt)

Comment: @DiliniPeiris here is a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format and another https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

Comment: @TimothyTruckle thanks!