# How to check if a number (type double) is multiple of another number (type double)?

Tags: java, modulo

Example I want to check if x = 2.4 is a multiple of y = 0.2.
I have used the modulus operator but it is giving result as false.

I have tried

```
if (x % y == 0 )   // Giving False
if (x % y == 0.0 )   // Giving False
if (x % y == 0.00 )   // Giving False
```

Is there another way to check for this?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to do modulo of a fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864568/is-it-possible-to-do-modulo-of-a-fraction)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947044/how-do-i-use-modulus-for-float-double

Comment: have you checked the result of `x % y` - floating point primitives in java are not exact (`2.4 = 2.399999999999999911182...` and `0.2 = 0.200000000000000011102...`) so the remainder operator with `double` is not the best solution (maybe you can use `BigDecimal`)

Comment: If one of the answers has solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark near the upper left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* class will give you the precision you're looking for.

```java
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("2.4");
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal("0.2");
double remainder = x.remainder(y).doubleValue();
System.out.println(remainder);
```

Output

```
0.0
```

Make sure to provide your data as *String* values, otherwise the same floating-point error will occur.
The *[BigDecimal#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double))* method will suffice as well. 
You can use *[String#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(double))* if need be.

For example,

```java
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(2.4d);
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(0.2d);
double remainder = x.remainder(y).doubleValue();
System.out.println(remainder);
```

Output

```
0.1999999999999998
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to `BigDecimal` using `valueof` (*not* the `new BigDecimal(double)` constructor) and then take the remainder and compare it with zero.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = 2.4;
    double y = 0.2;
    System.out.format("%.1f is a multiple of %.1f: %b%n",
        x, y, isMultipleOf(x, y));
}

public static boolean isMultipleOf(double d1, double d2) {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(d1).remainder(BigDecimal.valueOf(d2))
        .compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0;
}
```

Comment: As a note, you can even use the _doubleValue_ method, which would return a _0_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(Math.round(x*1000)%Math.round(y*1000))
```

This will not work for values with too many digits after the decimal point, but you can always use a bigger multiplier than 1000 if you need it.